# Using Django-modeltranslation in combination with PostgreSQL SearchVector

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-modeltranslation](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to translate model fields. And suppose I have the following model (where the name is translated in the DB):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
```

Then, in a DRF view, I have an endpoint that takes a query text and searches through the book names using this code:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank

class BookView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        q = request.get('q')
        vector = SearchVector('name') # this is where the issue is
        query = SearchQuery(q)
        matches = Book.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query))\
                      .filter(rank__gt=0.1)\
                      .order_by('-rank')
        # etc.
```

This works great when I was working with English only. But now I added a new language, and all aspects of the localisation are working fine, except this search. It's looking at the `name_en` field values only.

If the target language is German for example, and I explicitly change the following line from:

```
vector = SearchVector('name')
```

to:

```
vector = SearchVector('name_de')
```

Then the search works over the correct field. Is there a way to pass in the correct field to `SearchVector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can just use [`get_language()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language):

```py
from django.utils.translation import get_language
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank

class BookView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        q = request.get('q')
        vector = SearchVector(f'name_{get_language()}')
        query = SearchQuery(q)
        matches = Book.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query))\
                      .filter(rank__gt=0.1)\
                      .order_by('-rank')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also add language config to a query in ordeer to make it 'conscious' about the language.

```
    query= SearchQuery(q,config="your_lang",search_type='websearch')
```